# NoMethodError: undefined method `initializer' for Cucumber:Module

Tags: ruby, jenkins, cucumber, rake, hudson

I am trying to run some cucumber tests using rake. When I call `rake kickoff` (@kickoff is the tag within my feature file) I get the following error:

```
rake aborted!
NoMethodError: undefined method `initializer' for Cucumber:Module
/webdata/jenkins/jobs/kickoff_build/workspace/Rakefile:2:in `<top (required)>'
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

I have already run bundler and all necessary gems are installed.

Here is the contents of my `kickoff_build` feature file:

```
@kickoff

Feature: Automated Regression Build
  Scenario: As an automation developer, I want to kick off the build
    Given the CI server is configured correctly
    When the tag in line 1 of this file is called via a rake task
    Then this test should run and pass
```

Here is the content of my `Rakefile`:

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'cucumber'
require 'cucumber/rake/task'
require 'cuke_sniffer'

Cucumber::Rake::Task.new(:kickoff, :build) do |t|
  tags = '--tags ~@wip --tags ~@manual --tags ~@known_defect'
  t.cucumber_opts = "--format html --out results/result.html --format pretty #{tags} --format junit --out features/reports"
end
```

Comment: What version of cucumber are you running?

Comment: Version 2.0.0 beta 3

Comment: Do you run `bundle exec rake kickoff` or just `rake kickoff`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a bug present in the betas for cucumber `2.0.0`.

Upgrade to cucumber `~> 2.0` and you should be fine.

Comment: Wow thank you. I can't test it now as I have left work for the weekend, but I'll test it first thing Monday and let you know the result.

Comment: I also see this same error when attempting to run using `rake kickoff`. Is this due to the same bug?

Comment: Probably, I just wanted to eliminate conflicts with system gems as an error source.

Comment: You should accept my answer if this resolved your issue, @FluffyKittens

Comment: Sorry about that! It was definitely my issue.